# Python module import fails on website

Tags: python, import, module

I have a module (pyScss) I want to use on a remote server (a web host), and since I don't have permissions to install in the usual directory, I installed in a different one (`/home/private/lib/python`) and modified `$PYTHONPATH`. Now the trouble comes in trying to import my module.

In the interpreter and on the command line, everything works fine. I can import the module and use it and everything. Even if I say `> python -S`, I can use `site.addsitedir('/home/private/lib/python')` and everything works fine.

Now let's say I have a file `/home/public/test.py` that uses the module `scss`. Typing `> python /home/public/test.py` on the command line works, but loading `http://mywebsite.com/test.py` fails—"No module named scss". The values of `sys.path` and `sys.executable` agree in both cases.

What is going on here?

Comment: What user is the web server running as? Does it have rights to access that directory?

Comment: Good call. That was the problem :<

Comment: You should close this question if you don't need it answered anymore.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, as I have only recently abandoned my quarters of lurkerdom, but—how do I do that?